# Getting path of project directory in xcode (PathKit)

Tags: swift, xcode

I am just trying the Stencil Template Engine by Kyle Fuller. To use the *.stencil files I put them into the project directory. To refer to them I do a very ugly hack:

```
let pathOfThisFile = #file
let pathOfDirectory = Path(pathOfThisFile.replacingOccurrences(of: "/main.swift", with: ""))
let environment = Environment(loader: FileSystemLoader(paths: [pathOfDirectory]))
```

This way I can render Stencil Templates this way:

```
let testoutput = try? environment.renderTemplate(name: "test.stencil", context: context)
```

To me this seems very nasty. Is there a better way? I do not want to use absolute Paths.

If you have a more elegant way please let me know.

Comment: Doesn't look too nasty to me, really.

Comment: How about just use `Path.current` if you feel nasty?